# Fparsec vs regular expressions

Tags: regex, fparsec

What is the advantage of using a library like FParsec for parsing text over using plain regular expressions from a .NET language?

Comment: Why is this being closed as primarily opinion-based? Either there are objective advantages to FParsec (flexibility, performance, etc.) or there are not (in which case the answer is: there are no objective advantages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FParsec can recognise (at least) [context-free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) whereas regular expressions can only recognise [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), at least without using somewhat hacky extensions.

One example of something you can't do with a regular language is *bracket matching*, i.e. tracking the number of opening and closing brackets and make sure that they match up.

Of course you can emulate this with regular expressions by using them repeatedly, but embedding the behaviour into a single parser is significantly cleaner.

Comment: FParsec also generates error messages, and if you follow certain guidelines (http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/performance-optimizations.html), an FParsec parser can be faster...